# Error during deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

Class that I am serializing:

```
public class StyleProperties
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public StyleType Type;

    public ShapeStyleProperties ShapeStyle;
    public TextStyleProperties TextStyle;
}
```

Part that is responsible for serializing data:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StyleProperties));

PPT.Presentation pres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
CustomXMLParts parts = pres.CustomXMLParts;

//var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyCustomData));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, styleProperties);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(myStr);

    parts.Add(myStr);

}
```

Part that is responsible for deserializing:

```
    public static T ReturnObjectFromXML<T>(CustomXMLPart customXMLPart)
    {

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(customXMLPart.XML)))
        {
            DataContractSerializer formatter0 =
                new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

            return (T)formatter0.ReadObject(reader);
        }        

   }
```

Error occurs of course in line

```
return (T)formatter0.ReadObject(reader);
```

Error which I am getting:

> Error in line 1 position 23. Expecting element 'StyleProperties' from
>   namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PPT_Styles_Tool'..
>   Encountered 'Element'  with name 'StyleProperties', namespace ''.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><StyleProperties xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="sdfdzdfvvc" Description="" Type="Shape">
  <ShapeStyle>
    <Location>
      <Left>521.6249</Left>
      <Top>37.75</Top>
    </Location>
    <Size>
      <Width>198.125</Width>
      <Height>54</Height>
    </Size>
    <Fill>
      <Color>
        <SchemeColor>ppFill</SchemeColor>
        <ObjectThemeColor>msoThemeColorAccent1</ObjectThemeColor>
        <ColorType>msoColorTypeScheme</ColorType>
      </Color>
      <Transparency>System.__ComObject</Transparency>
      <Visible>msoFalse</Visible>
      <FillType>msoFillSolid</FillType>
    </Fill>
    <AutoShapeType>msoShapeNotPrimitive</AutoShapeType>
    <Rotation>0</Rotation>
    <LockAspectRatio>msoFalse</LockAspectRatio>
    <BlackWhiteMode>msoBlackWhiteAutomatic</BlackWhiteMode>
    <TextFrame>
      <MarginTop>0</MarginTop>
      <MarginLeft>0</MarginLeft>
      <MarginBottom>0</MarginBottom>
      <MarginRight>0</MarginRight>
    </TextFrame>
    <TextFrame2>
      <WordWrap>msoTrue</WordWrap>
    </TextFrame2>
    <LineStyle>
      <DashStyle>msoLineSolid</DashStyle>
      <Transparency>0</Transparency>
      <Weight>0.75</Weight>
      <Color>
        <SchemeColor>ppForeground</SchemeColor>
        <ObjectThemeColor>msoThemeColorText1</ObjectThemeColor>
        <ColorType>msoColorTypeScheme</ColorType>
      </Color>
      <Visible>msoFalse</Visible>
      <LineStyle>msoLineSingle</LineStyle>
      <LinePattern>msoPatternMixed</LinePattern>
    </LineStyle>
    <ShapeTFAutoSize>ppAutoSizeNone</ShapeTFAutoSize>
  </ShapeStyle>
  <TextStyle>
    <Font/>
    <ParagraphFormat/>
  </TextStyle>
</StyleProperties>
```

So from that what I see there is no namespace: 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PPT_Styles_Tool'   But how can I repair it? I am rookie at working with XML documents and especially serializing/deserializing XML data to/from objects

Comment: Please edit your post to include the _real_ XML. It looks like you got that from the debugger, and it includes escape characters `\"`.

Comment: You're serializing with `XmlSerializer` and then trying to read it back with `DataContractSerializer`.  You should pick one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[XmlElement]` attribute:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "StyleProperties", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PPT_Styles_Tool")]
public class StyleProperties
{
//...
```

Also, if you use the XmlSerializer to serialize, then you should use the XmlSerializer to deserialize. Not the DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I've just had to change  XmlElement into XMLRoot, because XMLElement was not accepted by debugger.